# Can I ask a question here if it is not already asked but the answer is in the internet?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have the question below:

> How to change the default path of the Skype for business's received files. Where can I find the settings to change the default path?
>
> [skype-for-business](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/skype-for-business)

I can find the answers for this question in the Internet but not in the Super User.
In this case, can I post the question here or should not?

Comment: This site doesn't invent knowledge, it compiles it.  In the best cases, it also explains it.  Virtually every answer here is knowledge that came from somewhere else.  If an on-topic question can be useful to others, and you can also share an answer, go for it.  But make it self-contained here, don't just provide a link to an answer somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask and [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Please make sure you correctly reference any quoted material in your answer. See [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).

You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).