# Should I post a question if the answer is easily available on google? But not a dupe on the SE Network?

Tags: discussion

I just asked [a Question relating to BCLK on CPU/BIOS Settings](https://superuser.com/questions/1317594/how-does-bclk-work-in-regards-to-overclocking-non-k-intel-cpus) and got an interesting comment >>

```
Before you do that I suggest doing more research. I literally searched for BCLK and found the answer to your question (multiple results) – Ramhound 7 mins ago.
```

I was blown away as I know this user is a frequent SE user as I've seen his comments on old questions and new. I would think this falls perfectly under what this site is all about. Good Questions with community voted answers.

I tried looking on SU Meta but only found questions (similiar), but the answers related to asking "Self Answer" type questions which this was not. My theory is that I can leave the answer to somebody who needs the rep if it's "that simple". But to me, it wasn't. (And not a Dupe as far as I could find on SU) I spent hours reading on OC'ing non K intel CPU's (something I didn't realize was possible) but I came across too many abbreviations to make heads or tails of most of it. IE: Increase your BLCK and lock you MCE. (To a noob in CPU OC'ing that's total jargon!). Which as an IT guy I can relate to, but I'm usually not on the receiving end of the "confused" spectrum.

[Asking questions that are clearly answered elsewhere](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6072/asking-questions-that-are-clearly-answered-elsewhere)

[Can I ask a question here if it is not already asked but the answer is in the internet?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12432/can-i-ask-a-question-here-if-it-is-not-already-asked-but-the-answer-is-in-the-in)

Update: While the above post linked were the inspiration for my question, I'm mostly curious if it's okay etiquette to ask questions that are easily answered via Google.

My thought would be yes, because we want to build the stack exchange knowledge base and I feel more confident when I see an answer on a stack exchange that has been voted on by the community versus just because it shows up in Google results doesn't mean it's correct.

(I host a Blog that shows up in Google results all the time and I don't pretend to be 100% accurate on my blog lol)

Comment: I'm not convinced it's necessary to identify the user who made the comment and suggest editing out the username. It seems sufficient to mention what the comment was and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

This *isn't* what comments are supposed to be used for. Voting works well enough for telling someone something is off topic, and this sort of comments only result in noise. This sort of thing dosen't quite make me a happy camper.

I *personally* am not all that fond of "define this thing for me" questions - now if I was asking the question, I'd reword it somewhat .

I've asked a similar question in the past and pulling in what I did right and [wrong in the past](https://superuser.com/questions/523354/what-is-fb-and-vid-usage-in-asus-gpu-tweak)

Context would be nice. You're trying to OC a system and you're tweaking a value. Asking what that would *alter* and its *effects* would make for a better question than asking to explain what BCLK is.

> Can anybody explain the "formula" for increasing BCLK eg:

Is practically asking about effects. but "How would adjusting the bclk effect the clock speeds of my PC" would fit in here.

In a sense, this question *could* do with a rewrite, but I don't see any positive changes coming from the comment thread.

... also bclk is base clock rate.

I've edited most of your question. I do believe it would be an improvement over what it currently uisIts just a bit of reordering and I hope it maintains the core of what you need to know.

You will likely need to explain what the image, and the chunk of text below is, its less than clear.

Comment: Your answer is very specific to the details of my question that I linked and the comment. While the comment and question were the inspiration, you didn't answer the main question in this meta post

Comment: +1 for the Edit though, much better thanks

Comment: I just noticed I never repeated the title question inside of the main body, but the title question still stands.

Comment: Well that sort of edits is what I really wish people would do. Well, the question as written wasn't that good, and we turned that from "an easy to google question" to one that forms a useful body of knowledge. The orginal question was pretty bad IMO but it was fixable. It isn't enough to complain, when we can also basically point people at the right direction. You *won't* be asking a trivially googleable definition question again, right?